# C++ 11: What type of callable should I use when using sorted vector to simulate map

Tags: c++11

Scott Meyer's *Effective STL* showed an example of using sorted vector of `pair<key, value>` to simulate a map or multimap. In order to sort the vector and later look up the elements in the vector, he has to create a functor **DataCompare** where there are 3 overloaded function `operator()`: one that takes two pair object for sorting; two that take a `pair` and a `key` because in algorithms like `lower_bound`, `equal_range`, we don't know the order in which the key object and the pair object are passed to the custom comparison functor:

```
typedef pair<string, int> Data; // type held in the "map"

class DataCompare { // class for comparison
public:
    bool operator()(const Data& lhs, const Data& rhs) const  // comparison func for sorting
    {
        return keyLess(lhs.first, rhs.first);
    }
    bool operator()(const Data& Ihs, const Data::first_type& k) const // comparison func for lookups
    { //(form 1)
        return keyLess(lhs.first, k);
    }
    bool operator()(const Data::first_type& k, const Data& rhs) const // comparison func for lookups
    { // (form 2)
        return keyLessfk, rhs.first);
    }
....
```

Now that we have C++11, we have lambda and `std::bind` and `std::function` to replace functors. But how do I use lambda or `std::bind` or `std::function` to deal with the uncertainty of the order the arguments are passed in (lookup) algorithms like `lower_bound`, `upper_bound` and `equal_range`?

In http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/, the description for **comp** seems to suggest I can create a lambda whose first parameter can be the `pair` and the second parameter can be of the same type as `key`. However, inside the implementation of `lower_bound`, it can switch the order in calling the lambda. In g++ (my version is 4.8.4), I got the following error:

> ... `else if (__comp(__val, *__middle))`
>
> ...
>   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const std::basic_string’ to ‘const ms2dict& {aka const std::pair< std::basic_string< char>, std::basic_string< char> >&}’

Here the `else if (__comp(__val, *__middle))` is using the lambda but passing the arguments in reverse order. Is there a way to create a universal callable object that deal with this problem?

Comment: Create a class template `CompWrapper<T>` that is implicitly convertible from both `T` and `pair<T,U>`. Use it for the arguments of the lambda.

Comment: With C++11, the order is no longer uncertain. The comparator should always be called with the container's element as the first argument, and the lookup value as the second. If you observe different behavior with your compiler, then its implementation is non-conforming, or perhaps written to C++03 spec.

Comment: @n.m. how do i make pair<T, U> implicitly convertible to CompWrapper<T>? Specialize CompWrapper<T> for when T is pair<T,U>?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik 　my g++ is version 4.8.4 on ubuntu. I do observer this (non-conforming?) behavior...

Comment: Write a one-argument constructor `template<class U> CompWrapper(const pair<T,U>&)` and don't mark it explicit.

Comment: Do you use -std=c++11?

Comment: @n.m. yes. I did use -std=c++11

Comment: [This program using asymmetric comparators](http://rextester.com/TQI69740) compiles for me with gcc.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik try changing one of your `lower_bound`s to `equal_range`. It gives the same error as what I got.

Comment: Ah, yes. `std::lower_bound` needs to compare `element < value`. `std::upper_bound` needs to compare `value < element`. And `std::equal_range` needs to compare in both directions.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oh. So that means I either have to call `low_bound` and `upper_bound` separately with different lambdas, or use n.m's advice to convert both key and pair to a common type to do comparisons, right?

Comment: That, or stick to the original plan and write a named class with three overloads of `operator()`. I for one don't see anything wrong with that, no pressing need to switch to lambdas.